# Unable to draw single particle effect at two places

Tags: libgdx, particles

I am using Libgdx ParticleEffect to draw a fire particle effect .

The issue I have is that when I try to render a ParticleEffect at two different locations within single game loop, only the last draw call has the effect drawn on screen. I update the Particle effect only once per game loop but set its position to two distinct locations and draw it. Is this a trivial problem with Libgdx ParticleEffect:

```
ParticleEffect effect = new PartcleEffect();
effect.load(gdx.files.internal("data/effect.particle"),atlas,"");
effect.start();
```

In render :

```
effect.update(deltaTime);

effect.setPosition(x1,y1);
effect.draw(batch);

effect.setPosition(x2,y2);
effect.draw(batch);
```

Can someone tell me why it isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

When you call `effect.setPosition(...)`, it changes the position of all the **emitters**, but **not of the particles**.  In libGDX, there is currently no way of changing the position of a single particle, so in order to draw particles at 2 locations, you must do the following:

```
// Pseudo-code
move effect at position 1
add particles
move effect at position 2
add particles
update effect
draw effect
```

You must create particles at the 2 different locations to achieve the effect you want.

Answer (score 1):

you have to create an array of pooled effects

```
Array<PooledEffect> effects = new Array<PooledEffect>();
```

so, in render(), you draw all effects from array.

```
for(int i = 0; i < blocos.size();i++){
            if(obj.colision(block.get(i),config)) {

                PooledEffect effect = block.get(i).getEffectPool().obtain();
                effect.setPosition(block.get(i).getX(), block.get(i).getY());
                effects.add(effect);

                blocos.remove(i);
            }

        }
```

Comment: I ended up doing the same :)

Comment: For better undestanding this, see also ParticleEffectPool class